# onsen-ui sliding menu opening twice

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onsen-ui

I have a sliding menu that I'm placing on each page in my app. Oddly though, on all pages other than the root home page, the sliding menu opens twice, side-by-side. I can't seem to figure out why this is occurring. I've set swipable from true to false, that didn't change anything. Also tried reveal/push for type, and that also did not provide a different result.

Any idea why this is occurring? Thanks!

```
<ons-sliding-menu
    var="app.slidingMenu"
    menu-page="sliding_menu.html"
    side="right"
    main-page="about-us-aboutInfo.html"
    type="push"
    max-slide-distance="260px"
    swipeable="false">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="about-us-aboutInfo.html">
    <ons-page>

        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center animated fadeIn">{{ title }}</div>
            <div class="right">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="app.slidingMenu.toggle()">
                    <i class="ion-navicon" style="font-size:32px; vertical-align:-6px;"></i>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <div class="about-us-aboutInfo">
            <div ui-view class="container">
                <div class="content animated fadeIn">
                    <h1 class="text-heading">{{ title }}</h1>
                    <div class="animated fadeIn">
                        <div ui-view ng-repeat="section in Source.sections">
                            <h1 class="text-heading">{{ section.heading }}</h1>
                            <p ng-repeat="paragraph in section.paragraphs">
                                {{ paragraph }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with opening twice, but perhaps my answer fix your problem. If not please reproduce the problem in Codepen or anything similar that we can see.

Comment: When I click the hamburger icon in the toolbar, the slideout menu opens. If I happen to click within that slideout menu, and pull it, a second instance is created right next to it. So, I see the same slideout menu twice, side-by-side.

Comment: That's really weird. There should be only 1 sliding menu in your app. Have you included more than 1 somehow? I'd like to see it in a Codepen if you can do it.

Comment: Your code seems fine, please post also the code of the sliding-menu page, maybe the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`swipeable`](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-sliding-menu.html#attributes) attribute instead of "swipable" :)

Comment: Thanks, I did fix that typo. Unfortunately, that didn't resolve the problem of two menus opening if I pull left. Is there a way to destroy all other instances once the slideout opens?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change:

```
var="app.slidingMenu"
```

to

```
var="app.slidingMenu.nameOfYourPage"
```

and

```
<ons-toolbar-button ng-click="app.slidingMenu.nameOfYourPage.toggle()">
```

so that each menu has its own variable name